# Using date_parse_from_format outputs date that is 1 day out?

Tags: php

I am parsing a formatted date into another format like this...

```
$ordersDate = 'Saturday 8th of July 2017 21:22:52 PM';
$parsed = date_parse_from_format("l jS \of F Y H:i:s A", $ordersDate);
$new = mktime(
$parsed['hour'], 
$parsed['minute'], 
$parsed['second'], 
$parsed['month'], 
$parsed['day'], 
$parsed['year']
);
$timestamp=$new;
$formatdate = gmdate("d/m/Y", $new);
echo $formatdate;
```

Why is this outputting ... 09/07/2017 and not 08/07/2017?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is caused by you make wrong date. If you use AM/PM, just use 12 hours format. If you use 24 hours format.

```
$ordersDate = 'Saturday 8th of July 2017 21:22:52 PM';
```

`21:22:52 PM` will be equivalent with `33:22:52` and that's why the date become next date

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Dolly. Works now!